# Entity Framework Code First with MVC : RuntimeBinder Exception error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, runtimeexception, viewbag, android-binder

I am using ASP.Net Core Web Application with MVC and EF Code First and my db is  MySQL. Here is the structure of my db:
[image]

I am trying to display data from the view bag and its giving me an error.
[image: This is index.cshtml]

Its complaining about foreach loop.

[image: browser error]

here is whats inside viewBag: This is kinda weird. Is it an infinite loop? What is the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `@` from the starting of `@foreach` => `foreach` loop. Hope it works.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention this code is inside .cshtml, it requires @foreach, if i remove @ it thinks its not a code.

Comment: @AlecTech you are using the `@foreach` inside the `@if` so there is no need to add `@` infront of foreach. Please try it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag.Employees is type of Employee & not EmployeeDate, I'll suggest to cast ViewBag.Employees to respective Datatype & use the same in foreach. It will help you to reduce runtime errors.